# Packaging and distributing an Windows Store App?

Tags: xaml, deployment, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

i want to create a package of my metro application to distribute it to my client for testing it .

These are the following steps i followed :-

select Store->Create App Package
Select Build a package to use locally only thats it what i did, but **my doubt** is :-

1) Where is the exact file entire executable file present/located or created when i packaged it (like .xap in windows phone application)????

2)which is the one particular file which is needed for me to send across so that it is deployable in any other machine and can run the app?????

3) What are the requirements the other machine needs to have for deploying my app and running , for sure i think it needs to have a windows 8 OS for running an metro app apart from the what else the other machine needs to have take my metro app deploy it and run out there locally for testing purpose ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When you run the Store->Create App Package option you can pick the output directory - it will default to an AppPackages directory in your project folder.  When the package creation is complete the generation window will contain a link that will take you to that directory.
2. There are multiple files required, an appx, a certificate file, resources, dependencies, and a powershell script.  You'll get subdirectories in the AppPackages directory with a naming convention that identifies the build type and target platform - like App74_1.0.0.2_x64_Debug_Test.  Everything in a directory is required (for whatever platforms is sepcificied: ARM, x64, x86)if you want to bring the application to another machine.
3. The other machine will need Windows 8, and in order to run the application on that machine, it will need a developer license. If you simply execute the PowerShell script that's in the package directory it will procure a temporary developer license if one is not found (that, of course, requires internet connectivity). It will also install a signing certificate for the app (which is another file in the set that is created by the packaging operation.